# Let's encrypt certificate not working for domain.tld

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am currently the administrator of [move2space](https://www.move2space.de)
I have configured a letsencrypt certificate for the site (including move2space.de and www.move2space.de)
The problem is: While the www subdomain works, without it I get SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in firefox and NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in chrome.

My nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name move2space.de www.move2space.de localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name move2space.de www.move2space.de localhost;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://move2space:80;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Yes, my certificate was created with `-d move2space.de -d www.move2space.de`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The DNS record of `move2space.de` points to a completely different IP address than `www.move2space.de`.

```
$ nslookup www.move2space.de

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    move2.lrt.mw.tum.de
Address:  129.187.219.4
Aliases:  www.move2space.de


$ nslookup move2space.de

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    move2space.de
Addresses:  2a00:1158:1000:400::6b
          80.67.21.107
```

Correct your DNS record and it should work.